# Can you name reports in SAS EG?

Tags: sas, report, proc, enterprise-guide

In EG I want to create a report and export it using a macro variable in the name of the export file, so that if I re-run the report and the variable changes (i.e. a timestamp) it will not override my previous report.

When I create a report using proc report is automatically names my report after the code that created it.  The export function is created in a point and click function and I can't use macro variables in there.  Is there a simple way to name a report in the proc report procedure?

[process flow screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McGHc.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can 
You will have to use proc export or do a datastep using infile

here is an example with proc export

```
proc sql outobs=1;
select datetime :into dt 
from table;

proc export data=<report_data> 
 OUTFILE="<path_to_file>/report_&dt..csv" 
DBMS=CSV LABEL REPLACE;
RUN;
```

that should work well!